# How to recover frontend and backend css after deploy command

Tags: magento2

I have done below steps but after this frontend and backend css fonts will not working properly in magento2.

Remove pub/static //not .htaccess

Remove var/cache

Remove var/composer_home

Remove var/generation

Remove var/page_cache

Remove var/view_preprocessed

Then open up app/etc/di.xml find the path 
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink
 and replace it with Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy

And finally run this:
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Answer (score 0):

I have been facing strange issue, as the part moving modifications in static content. we removed pub/static and deployed setup:static-content:deploy.

After doing this, files are generated properly in pub/static folder but when i load front end, styles are vanished.

As in the source the file paths are loading with version1483082446

root/static/version1483082446/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_US/mage/calendar.css

I have followed below commands, but my styles are not loading in frontend.

Answer (score 0):

- Delete var/cache var/page_cache generated var/view_proceesed pub/static/frontend pub/static/adminhtml
- Perform `setup:upgrade di:compile content:deploy cache:flush`
- Give 777 permission to the pub var and generated folder.